# Classic ASP - Need Help Updating Stamp Duty Calculator Percentages

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I have been asked to update the Stamp Duty Calculator Percentages but it is written is asp and I've never really used it before. I have updated the percentages but when I calculate the number it seem to be off by around £100 to £1000.

**http://www.stampdutycalculator.org.uk/** Here is what the Calculator totals should be.

**http://smart-search.mobi/cal_test/purchase.asp** This is the one I'm working on.

**http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/mortgages/stamp-duty** Correct vaules and precentages.

This is some examples of what the outcome should be.

**If £125000 is entered £0 stamp duty should appear (This one works)**

**If £185000 is entered £1200 stamp duty should appear (£1295 shows up for me)**

**If £275000 is entered £3750 stamp duty should appear (£3850 show up for me)**

**If £937500 is entered £37500 stamp duty should appear (This one works)**

**If £2100000 is entered £165750 stamp duty should appear (£165900 shows up for me)**

---

**The new rates are:**

£0 - £125,000  0%,

£125,001 - £250,000 2%,

£250,001 - £925,000 5%,

£925,001 - £1.5 million 10%,

Over £1.5 million  12%

```
<%
dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, z, x, y, w, v
x = request("leasehold")
y = request("newbuild")
a = request("PurchasePrice")
CurrencySymbol ="£"
if x=yes then w=150
if y=yes then v=150
if a>=0 then b=775-w-v
if a>=100001 then b=800-w-v 'A = PurchasePrice | B = Legal Fees'
if a>=150001 then b=850-w-v
if a>=200001 then b=900-w-v
if a>=250001 then b=975-w-v
if a>=300001 then b=1050-w-v
if a>=400001 then b=1150-w-v
if a>=500001 then b=1275-w-v
if a>=600001 then b=1400-w-v
if a>=700001 then b=0
if b=0 then aa="Please Call to Discuss"


'***PRECENTS ARE HERE******'
if a>=125000 then d=a*0     '0%'
if a>=185000 then d=a*0.007 '0.7%
if a>=250000 then d=a*0.014 '1.4%'
if a>=510000 then d=a*0.03 '3.0%'
if a>=937500 then d=a*0.04 '4.0%'
if a>=2100000 then d=a*0.079 '7.9%'
'*******************'

if a>=0 then f=40        'Land Registry Fee ?'
if a>=50001 then f=70
if a>=80001 then f=120
if a>=100001 then f=190
if a>=200001 then f=270
if a>=500001 then f=540
g = 30
e = 160
c = FormatNumber((b*120/100-b),2) 'V.A.T ?'
h = FormatNumber((g*120/100-g),2)
l = formatnumber((b),2)
m = formatnumber((g),2)
n = formatnumber((f),2)
o = formatnumber((e),2)
p = formatnumber((c),2)
q = formatnumber((d),2)
r = formatnumber((h),2)
k = b+c
i = d+e+f+g+h
j = k+i
s = formatnumber((k),2)
t = formatnumber((i),2)
u = formatnumber((j),2)
v = formatnumber((a),2)
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's classic asp, not asp.net,  and it's using VBScript as the server side scripting language

I'm going to assume that your mathematics are correct.

You haven't closed any of your if statements with end if, I'm surprised this isn't throwing error messages.  Here's an example of the correct syntax.

```
if a>=700001 then b=0 end if
```

If you're checking the value of a text string then you need to use quotes - eg

```
if x="yes" then w=150 end if
```

Finally, I've done a view source on your form at purcase.asp. I notice that the value attributes of your leasehold and new build checkboxes are both "off".  Obviously they need to be "yes" to correspond with the Request() statements in the asp

Edit

Given the rates you've provided here's the code I'd write.

```
<%
a = Clng(Request("a"))
if a<=125000 Then d=(a*0)
Elseif a>125000 And a<=250000 then d=(a*0.02)  
Elseif a>250000 And a<=925000 then d=(a*0.05)
Elseif a>925000 And a<=1500000 then d=(a*0.1)
Elseif a>1500000 then d=(a*0.12)
End if
Response.write d
%>
```

Edit 2 - This is how I'd do it if I understand the new stamp duty rules correctly.  Note that £57,500, £33,750 and £2,500 are the maximum amounts you would pay respectively in the 10%, 5% and 2% bands.

```
<%
a = Clng(Request("a"))
if a<=125000 Then d=0
Elseif a>125000 And a<=250000 then d=((a-125000)*0.02)  
Elseif a>250000 And a<=925000 then d=2500+((a-250000)*0.05)
Elseif a>925000 And a<=1500000 then d=33750+2500+((a-925000)*0.1)
Elseif a>1500000 then d=57500+33750+2500+((a-1500000)*0.12)
End if
Response.write d
%>
```

Comment: VBScript doesn't require single-line `if` statements to be terminated with `end if`. The syntax is fine. (Adding `End If` on a single-line `If` is supported for the very obscure need to have `:`-separated statements past and outside of the conditional on the same line. Such code is better left unwritten.)

Comment: @EuroMicelli so the code is fine and the problem must be with the maths

Comment: @EuroMicelli - cheers, I didn't know that.  My point about quoting text strings still holds though,

Comment: @John ive made the ajustments but it seems to be the same. can you please explain the line if a>=185000 then d=a*0.007 '0.7%'

Comment: It means if a is greater than or equal to 185000 then d equals (a multiplied by 0.007). The 0.7% is a comment. single quotes are used in VBScript to comment text. Anything after a single quote will be ignored.

Comment: I've just made an addition to my answer

Comment: @John I got a error so I tried removing lines 2,8 & 9 and else ifs then code works but im still getting the wrong result its like 10k higher on some vaules I put in I dont understand.

Comment: here is a list of vaules results and percentages can anyone help me figure out were im going wrong? http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/mortgages/stamp-duty

Comment: Haven't the rules for stamp duty changed, so that if you pay say £130,000 you're only charged on the difference between 130,000 and 125,000 rather than on the full amount of 130,000

Comment: @John I think you might be right, I am trying to read up on it but it's very confusing.

Comment: @John how would I go about changing this ?